# What is the range of $ y = (\operatorname{arccot} x) (\operatorname{ arccot} ( - x)) $

Tags: trigonometry, maxima-minima

What is the range of $ y =  (\operatorname{ arccot x }) (\operatorname{ arccot{ - x }}) $. I solved this problem with right answer using AM GM inequality. But I received a lot of  criticism for using AM GM inequality here on this site as it does not give sharp bounds.  So is there a better way? I was thinking about Jensen's inequality but that doesn't work.

[What is wrong with my solution of maximum value of $ \sin \frac {A}{2} + \sin \frac{B}{2} + \sin \frac{C}{2} $ in a triangle ABC?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3215956/what-is-wrong-with-my-solution-of-maximum-value-of-sin-frac-a2-sin-f)

[The side of a triangle inscribed in a given circle subtends angles $a, b, $ and $ y$ at the center.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3214943/the-side-of-a-triangle-inscribed-in-a-given-circle-subtends-angles-a-b-and)

[What is wrong with this solution of find the least value of $ \sec^6 x +\csc^6 x + \sec^6 x\csc^6 x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3168377/what-is-wrong-with-this-solution-of-find-the-least-value-of-sec6-x-csc6-x)

Comment: Can you please provide some context and show what you have tried? What is more, there are some issues with your LaTeX code. Use `\operatorname{arccot}` instead of `\arccot`.

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis I did say I solved this problem with right answer using AM GM what more could I add?

Comment: You could read [this guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) on writing a good question. You could offer people some context, show them what you've tried. You say you received criticism of MSE for using AM/GM; can you provide a link? BTW: a better way to typeset your equation: `y =  (\operatorname{arccot} x) (\operatorname{arccot}(-x))`

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis anything else I should add??

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis questions are put on hold even if they follow "this guide"https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30088/why-was-my-question-put-on-hold. So I doubt how helpful it is.

Comment: You're right, MSE doesn't work perfectly. I meant to say that the better you phrase your questions, the higher the chances that you'll get an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like [How do I prove that $\arccos(x) + \arccos(-x)=\pi$ when $x \in [-1,1]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1224415/how-do-i-prove-that-arccosx-arccos-x-pi-when-x-in-1-1),

arccot$(x)\cdot$arccot$(-x)=$arccot$(x)(\pi-$arccot$(x))=\left(\dfrac\pi2\right)^2-\left(\text{arccot }(x)-\dfrac\pi2\right)^2$